# How to remove duplicate values in list?

Tags: python, list, unique

Can you please help me find any builtin function or another solution to leave only unique values from the list. A `set(list)` didn't do the trick in this case. I wish to remove duplicates and source values so for example

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E']
result = ['A', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: @bigbounty, `set(list)` will only remove the duplicates, not the items that are duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use list comprehension for that following list:

```
mylist = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"]
result = [i for i in mylist if mylist.count(i)==1]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'D', 'E']
```

As side note do not use `list` as variable name as this is already built-in function name.

Comment: This has O(n^2) complexity. You can use  `collections.Counter` (or implement your own O(n) counter) to reduce it to O(n)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simple and efficient (and in Python 3.6+ will preserve order):

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"]
result = [key for key, count in Counter(mylist).items() if count == 1]
```

Gives

```
['A', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: I like this better than my group-by method. way easier to read.

Comment: Good, concise O(n) solution

Answer (score 0):

you just need to recheck for count after you have the set.
instead of going through the whole list and filtering (doesnt make good time)

```
   newlist=[]
   for a in set(l):
       if l.count(a) == 1:
           newlist.append(a)
```

Please do not use "list" as a name for your variable. the list is "l" here.

Comment: You don't need to convert back to `list`, `for a in set(l):` will work just as well

Comment: Ah yes, about the list I guess I need to work with lists again so I got used to that.

Comment: BTW, this is also O(n^2) in the worst-case. If `l` has N unique elements set(l) still contains all elements of `l`. Then calling `l.count` on every element of `l` gives O(n^2)

Comment: yeh if N == n.. you can just check len(set) vs len(list) and not have to do a counter at all, guess that could be a condition... an O(n) counter such as collections.counter would still have Nxn total complexity no? (after the counter you would have to check the N list for those with count == 1), Oh wait, that might be n+N, depending on how its coded, that sounds better.. I did just check collections.. its a n log(N) complexity not O(n) hmm

Comment: Using `collections.Counter` (correctly) can provide O(n) solution (O(2*n)) is still O(n), and is much better than O(n^2). See Steven Rumbalski's answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

data = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E']
g = filter(lambda x: len(list(x[1])) == 1, groupby(sorted(data), lambda x: x))

result = [x[0] for x in g]
```

And I get: `['A', 'D', 'E']`

Comment: This fails if `data` is not sorted (as `groupby` usually expects). Try with `data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'E']`

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for the tip

Comment: Why the explicit identity key?

Comment: @HeapOverflow just a habit to keep things consistent and minimize modifications when data structures get more complex AND also demonstrate what the key actually is for those who aren't familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Find duplicates by iterating via a set of items to reduce number of iterations.

Then use subtraction of sets.

```
base_list = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E']
duplicates = [i for i in set(base_list) if base_list.count(i) > 1]
no_duplicates_list = list(set(base_list) - set(duplicates))
```

The result will be:

```
['D', 'E', 'A']
```

You can sort it if needed.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
for element in list:
    if list.count(element) > 1:
        list(filter((element).__ne__, x))
```

^^^ was to modify the list, if you want a new list with the values, use @Daweo's method.